# Get timings grouped on days basis

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I have an object:

```
var daysMapping = { 1: "MON", 2: "TUE", 3: "WED", 4: "THU", 5: "FRI", 6: "SAT", 7: "SUN" };
```

and an array of objects:

```
var timingsArr = [{ StartTime: "09:00:00",  EndTime: "13:00:00",  Days: [2,3,4,5] }, 
 { StartTime: "16:00:00",  EndTime: "19:00:00",  Days: [2,3,4,5,6]},
 { StartTime: "09:00:00",  EndTime: "14:00:00",  Days: [6,7] }];
```

I need timings to be grouped in below manner:

TUE - FRI

9:00 AM - 1:00 PM

4:00 PM - 7:00 PM

SAT

9:00 AM - 2:00 PM

4:00 PM - 7:00 PM

SUN

9:00 AM - 2:00 PM

I need to write a code in javascript to get such timings. here I need data for weekday basis. If timings are same for some days, then those timings can be grouped. However solutions are accepted in any language.

Comment: why is tue to fri and not sat included?

Comment: because saturday is having different timings(9:00 AM - 2:00 PM) where as compared to (9 AM - 1 PM) for Tue-Fri.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proposal which tries to group the same timings to a day group.

It uses an object `grouped` for the days with the time and later an array `combined` for the result set.

I skipped the part of changing the display of 12h clock.

```js
var daysMapping = { 1: "MON", 2: "TUE", 3: "WED", 4: "THU", 5: "FRI", 6: "SAT", 7: "SUN" },
    days = ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"],
    timingsArr = [{ StartTime: "09:00:00", EndTime: "13:00:00", Days: "[2,3,4,5]" }, { StartTime: "16:00:00", EndTime: "19:00:00", Days: "[2,3,4,5,6]" }, { StartTime: "09:00:00", EndTime: "14:00:00", Days: "[6,7]" }],
    grouped = {},
    combined = [];

timingsArr.forEach(function (a) {
    var days = JSON.parse(a.Days).forEach(function (d) {
        grouped[daysMapping[d]] = grouped[daysMapping[d]] || [];
        grouped[daysMapping[d]].push(a.StartTime + ' ' + a.EndTime);
    });
});
days.forEach(function (day, i) {
    if (!i || JSON.stringify(this.last.data) !== JSON.stringify(grouped[day])) {
        this.last = { days: [day], data: grouped[day] };
        combined.push(this.last);
        return;
    }
    this.last.days[1] =day;
}, {});

combined.forEach(function (a) {
    var p;
    if (a.data) {
        a.data.sort();
        p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = '<strong>' + a.days.join(' - ') + '</strong><br>' + a.data.join('<br>');
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
});
```

Comment: JS fiddle link for above solution:  https://jsfiddle.net/7xam74k6/

Comment: New link with timings in AM/PM:  https://jsfiddle.net/7xam74k6/2/